# css syntax a:hover on element inside id and class

Tags: css

I want to apply same style to

```
a, a:hover
```

of elements residing inside an id, class and element. What's the most valid and effective syntax?

Example:

```
#leftmenu .shortcuts ul li a, a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Regards,
//t

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS isn't that smart, so you'll have to explicitly write out that first part, again. As `@sdleihssirhc` noted, you can omit `li`, as `ul` elements are assumed to already contain `li`s, so the selector would still work:

```
#leftmenu .shortcuts ul a,
#leftmenu .shortcuts ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I'd consider giving that `ul` an `id`, as it would condense your CSS considerably:

```
#lm_ul a, #lm_ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Comment: Although, in all likelihood, it could be made a *little* more succinct by getting rid of the `li` part. And, if at all possible, the much better solution would be to just give the links a class name.

Comment: I was just editing in that second part you mentioned, but thanks for the `li` trick. I'm going to be using that in my code.

Comment: Thanks, excellent answers. SO is the best thing since bicycles.

Answer (score 0):

or you could just do something similar to apply to all links inside a container with an id="leftMenu"

CSS:

```
#leftMenu > * a, #leftMenu > * a:hover{ .... }
```

HTML:

```
 <ul>
    <li><span><a>item1</a></span></li>
    <li><p><a>item1</a></p></li>
    <li><div><a>item1</a></div></li>
    <li><em><a>item1</a></em></li>
</ul>
```

This will take into account every element a no matter what is wrapping the links inside the container with id="leftMenu"